# GWC & Geoserver different tiles

Tags: geoserver

I've configured Geoserver with GWC. I have a layer which is displayed well but when it's displayed by using GWC then some tiles are missing.
Geoserver and GeoWebCache are in the same machine and the tiles to be displayed are based on a Postgis table. I'm getting this issue with both Google Maps and Open Layers (included in GWC to display the tiles).

The data uses the SRID 4326 and I've checked in Postgis every geom is valid (st_isvalid function).

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sovivic

Answer (score 0):

After some days working on this problem, I've realised the coordinates of the bounding box of the layer calculated by Geoserver were wrong. I've changed these coordinates and GWC is showing the layer properly.

I hope it helps other users.